# How to count different rows and put them all in same table in SQL?

Tags: sql, join, group-by, count, dml

I want to count how many people are applied for each category in my database and put all of those counts in one table. I don't have exact idea how should I do that. I've done it already like this but I want to have all in one query, and not to do it like this for each category.

```
select
count(cc.fk_id_candidates) as 'category A' 
from candidate_category cc, candidate c, category cat
where c.id=cc.fk_id_candidates and cc.fk_id_category=cat.id and category.name='A';
```

From that code I get number of people applied for category A as an output, which is correct, but I just need the same info for other categories too. I tried with case but it's not working right.

Thank you.

Comment: If you could provide your sample data and output that would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You would typically add a `group by` clause on the category name and/or id:

```
select cat.category.name, count(*) cnt
from candidate_category cc
inner join candidate c on c.id = cc.fk_id_candidates and 
inner join category cat on cc.fk_id_category = cat.id
group by cat.id, cat.category.name;
```

Note that I changed your query to use standard joins (with the `on` keyword) rather than implicit joins (with commas in the `from` clause and conditions in the `where` clause) - this old syntax should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you have three tables:
- candidate_category cc, 
- candidate c, 
- category cat

Also, you have Created below relationship using the REFERENCES:

```
where c.id=cc.fk_id_candidates 
and cc.fk_id_category=cat.id 
and category.name='A;
```

Now, you must have all the three tables in one table already and you can view it by:
and this is very important step to find a common column where you can filter it and find the proper data you want.

```
Select * 

from candidate_category cc, 
candidate c, 
category cat 

where c.id=cc.fk_id_candidates 
and cc.fk_id_category=cat.id
```